# JSF component renderer

Tags: java, html, jsf

I'v build a JSF component which works fine, I can see that it's being rendered the way i want.
I have problem when open a pop up from the page.

when I return from the pop up I can in the component renderer that the attributes of the component are null. and so the html DOM element are not it was before I opened the popup.

when I reload the page the attributes gets their values.and the html DOM element back to normal.

Anyone know why ?

```
<MyComponent attr1="test1" attr2="test2">
</MyComponen>
```

Comment: what does your pop up do?does it submit something to your server ? at least that's where I would start investigating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the problem after overriede saveState and restoreState methods of UIComponentBase
in my component.